# Ionic Geolocation, No Permission on iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I've been trying to get the geolocation package to work for the past 3 hours and decided to ask for some help, maybe you can see something I can't.

I've followed the directions, and can not get the app to get permission on any iOS device for the location service.

**config.xml**

https://gist.github.com/keoir/90ea3b75fefed70495409fd5692ac5c0

**Package.json**

https://gist.github.com/keoir/285c4c04671f70c2473783052936af0d

**app.component.ts**

https://gist.github.com/keoir/2d09d7cc6956b507a47a59701f0e1aa2

Comment: Could you specify which iOS version and device/simulator you're using?

Comment: For me the problem was that I didn't add the cordova plugin since I was using capacitor. But apparently you still do need to add it manually.

Answer (score 9):

@dhanesekar's solution was erased every time I ran `ionic cordova build ios`.
To solve this, I added the following in config.xml:

```
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription">
   <string>Get Position</string>
</edit-config>
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription">
   <string>Get position</string>
</edit-config>
```

And after : `ionic cordova platform remove ios && ionic cordova platform add ios`

Answer (score 0):

add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription to the .plist.
 Open /platforms/ios/{project}/{project}-Info.plist and add the following:

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>[App Name] would like to access your location when running and displayed.</string>
```

Comment: Don't do this unless you are programming in Swift or Objective C (and not a hybrid framework). It will be erased everytime you rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue, I followed [this git doc](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation#ios-quirks) and succeeded finally.